# Map Control Genexus

Tags: genexus

tengo el siguiente problema, estoy avanzando en un proyecto que ve el resultado de una consulta en un mapa a través de GxMap Control. Tengo 1 WebPanel que contiene un mapa y se ve así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Termino el proyecto subo mi app al server de producción (con ip pública), hago la misma consulta ejecuto y veo esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pestañea la imagen pero luego la tapa con el error. Voy a la consola javascript y me encuentro con esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguien me puede dar una mano con esto?

Gracias abrazo,
Bruno

Comment: Yo mismo respondo, leyendo [En este link](https://marketplace.genexus.com/question.aspx?2335)
encontré como colocar la api key en el User Control. Ojo que hay que refrescar el cache. Saludos!
Bruno